# Jenkins (latest) list artifacts on project page

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a problem with the latest Jenkins. I am building a single module project and am trying to list the archived artifacts on the main project page. I am almost sure, it worked this way a few versions ago, but today i tried to build a single-module maven project in a fresh jenkins and after building, i have to click on "Module" then on the module (there is only one, since its a single-module project) and there are my archived artifacts.

So how can i list the artifacts at my main project page? And how would i list all artifacts if it were a multi-module project?

(I am almost sure, a few weeks ago, jenkins took the first project, so the configured pom.xml as the "jenkins project", not as a module in this project)

Comment: maybe you used a plugin before and now your are not/using another? So maybe the new/other plugin is not able to show your stored artifacts?

Comment: I am using the same plugin as before, the default "Maven Project" plugin which comes with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In the Post Build Actions section of your Jenkins job configuration, select "**Archive the artifacts**" and specify which files to archive. A link will then be shown on your main page of jenkin job.